# React Ant Design multiple files upload doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm in the process of sending multiple files from "React.js" by `formData.append()` to a backend.

At the backend(Spring boot), I was able to see that multiple files were saved well with postman.

The problem occurred in React.

(I'm using "Ant Design" that is React UI Library.)

Below is the source that append files to formdata with extra data.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('webtoonId', this.state.selectedToonId);
formData.append('epiTitle', this.state.epiTitle);
formData.append('eFile', this.state.thumbnail[0].originFileObj);
for( let i = 0; i< this.state.mains.length ; i++){
    formData.append('mFiles', this.state.mains[i].originFileObj);
}
uploadEpi(formData)
```

uploadEpi() is POST API.

Below is about state.

```
this.state = {
    toons: [],
    epiTitle :'',
    thumbnail : [],
    mains : [],
    selectedToonID : ''
}
```

When I submit, Text and single file are stored in the DB normally, but only multiple files cannot be saved.

There was no error. Just multiple files didn't be saved.

The state "mains" is configured as shown below.
[image]

I guess it's because I'm using Ant Design incorrectly.
(Ant Design : https://ant.design/components/upload/)

Why I guessed so, because when I add `multiple` attribute to `<Dragger>` like below,

```
<Dragger onChange={this.onChangeMain} beforeUpload={() => false} multiple={true}>
```

the state "mains" multiple files became `undefined`.

Below is `onChange={this.onChangeMain}`

```
onChangeMain=({ fileList })=> {
    this.setState({ mains : fileList }, function(){
        console.log(this.state)
    });
}
```

The bottom line is, I want to know how to upload multiple files through `<Upload>` (or `<Dragger>`) in "React Ant Design."

I don't know what should I do.

this is my github about this project.

I'd appreciate with your help. thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [/* fileListBase64 */, setFileListBase64] = useState<any[]>([]);


const propsUpload = {
  onRemove: (file:any) => {
      const index = fileList.indexOf(file);
      const newFileList:any = fileList.slice();
      newFileList.splice(index, 1);

      return setFileList(newFileList)
  },
  beforeUpload: (file:any) => {
    setFileList([...fileList, file]); 
    return false;
  },
  onChange(info:any) {
    setLoading(true);
    const listFiles = info.fileList;
    setFileList(listFiles); 
    
    const newArrayFiles  = listFiles.map((file:any) => file.originFileObj? (file.originFileObj) : file );
    
    const anAsyncFunction = async (item:any) => {
      return convertBase64(item)
    }
    
    const getData = async () => {
      return Promise.all(newArrayFiles.map((item:any) => anAsyncFunction(item)))
    }
    
    getData().then(data => {
      /*  setFileSend(data) */
      setFileListBase64(data);
      setLoading(false);
      //    console.log(data);
    });
  },
  directory: true,
  fileList: fileList,
};

const convertBase64 = (file:File) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      resolve(fileReader?.result);
    }
    fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
      reject(error);
    }
  })
}

const handleDeleteListFiles = () => {
  setFileList([]);
  setFileListBase64([]);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are overriding the value of `mFiles`.

```
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('webtoonId', this.state.selectedToonId);
 formData.append('epiTitle', this.state.epiTitle);
 formData.append('eFile', this.state.thumbnail[0].originFileObj);

 let mFiles = [];

 for( let i = 0; i< this.state.mains.length ; i++){
    mFiles[i] = this.state.mains[i].originFileObj; 
 }

 formData.append('mFiles', mFiles)

 uploadEpi(formData)
```

Comment: thx for your answer, but when I change like that, error occured.
  ```Line 73:36:  'mFiles' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.```

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, I have updated my answer @JH

Comment: ```Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"]```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try again and now I hope it will resolve your problem @JH

Comment: Same error occured, but Thank you so much for your coment.

Comment: Hey. is your error got resolved ? i encountered the same issue.

Comment: I don't know if it is resolved or not...I think you should ask a question with error log. @NidhiDadiya

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can work:  `formData.append('mFiles[]', mFiles)`
If you add `[]` to the string it should not overwrite but add to the array