# Upload multiple files in Antd Dragger in one request as array

Tags: reactjs, antd

I wonder if it is possible to upload multiple files with Upload.Dragger from Ant Design UI library in one post request.
Currently, it is working fine sequentially, uploading them one by one, one request per file. But I want it to take all files into one array and  send this array into the request

The working example is available in  [example from docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/83xj8)

Documentation for Dragger is [here](https://ant.design/components/upload/)

```js
import { Upload, message } from 'antd';
import { InboxOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const { Dragger } = Upload;

const props = {
  name: 'file',
  multiple: true,
  action: 'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76',
  onChange(info) {
    const { status } = info.file;
    if (status !== 'uploading') {
      console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
    }
    if (status === 'done') {
      message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
    } else if (status === 'error') {
      message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
    }
  },
  onDrop(e) {
    console.log('Dropped files', e.dataTransfer.files);
  },
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Dragger {...props}>
    <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
      <InboxOutlined />
    </p>
    <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
    <p className="ant-upload-hint">
      Support for a single or bulk upload. Strictly prohibit from uploading company data or other
      band files
    </p>
  </Dragger>,
  mountNode,
);
```

Comment: My own endpoint accepts array, but the one on demo probably wont accept

Comment: You should be able to manipulate the request with `customRequest` property. Basically bypass the default api request and create your own

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Ant Design multiple files upload doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067560/react-ant-design-multiple-files-upload-doesnt-work)